# Adding CSS to an react project like angular cli script. Is it possible?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, less

I am angular user and i got a new project in my hands that i need to learn react. I am in very beggining, and my doubt is very very simple i think.
So, in angular you can add your css in the file angular.json (styles) right? And that css are available for all components that you will create.
So, in react i am looking and looking and i can't find an answer. The only way is import the file in all components?
I have a css file that i need for all components and i don't want import that file in all components.
Is there other way on react?
Thank you for the answers.

Comment: import that main css file in the entry point, ie at `App.jsx`, so that it'll be available across all components

Comment: doesn't work like i want because i have two files one with variables and other with simple css and the variables never work a

Comment: Import both of the files or if you're using any pre-processor you can import the partials into main file and import that main css file into App.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is the code in your styles.css file.

```
.container{
background: goldenrod;
height: 80vh;
}
```

Then you can link this file in any React Component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './styles.css';

class Cont extends Container{

render(){
 return (

   <div className={classes.container}>
       <p>Hi</p>
   </div>
)
}
}
```

Comment: i am not talking about that
i wanna put 2 files as global and i don't want import anymore that files. If those files are global i can use in all components